# Samba Public Share asking for authentication

Tags: nautilus, samba

**Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS**
I installed samba following this https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview    . I didn't make any change to samba.conf file. I used nautilus for **Local Network Share** and make an public sharing folder.

Now when i try to access that folder from another device it asks for authentication. And when i give my info i created while setting up samba using ubuntu documentation it gives me access. But it is a public folder and i wanted to share it in my local network without any authentication. I don't know what i am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the shared folder located?

If you created a share at /home/your-user-name/Public for example it will not work.

Not because of samba but because Ubuntu 22.04 changed the default permissions on home folders from 755 to 750: The owner of the folder is the only one that can access or even traverse the folder - either locally or across the network.

[] One option is to change it back to the old Ubuntu defaults:

```
chmod o+rx /home/your-user-name
```

Or even just set the folder to be traversable by others:

```
chmod o+x /home/your-user-name
```

[] Another option is to force the guest user to be you = at least for all these shares.

Since you are using **Local Network Share** edit /etc/samba/smb.conf

Right under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line add this one - using your own user name:

```
force user = your-user-name
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Note: THe same thing will happen if you share a folder at /media/your-user-name/XXX. THe best thing here is to use the `force user` approach.

Comment: Thanks 


It worked (force user method )

Comment: I will add that https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server recommends using /srv/samba not ~/Public

Answer (score 0):

To allow **guests** to connect to your samba share it's the easiest way to add a new user using `useradd` which has at least read permissions to your share.

let's say you added a new user called **publicsmb** and gave that user read permissions to your share.

you would need to tell samba to use that specific user for public access, your `smb.conf` could contain something like this:

```
[publicsmb]
path = /mnt/yourpublicshare
public = yes
writeable = yes
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
force user = publicsmb
```