# Can’t read own samba share

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I have Ubuntu 20.04 server running as a router and smb network share and a windows 10 client using the share by mapping it to drive Z.

The share is located at /home/user/public/ and is drwxrwxr-x

I created a file called test.txt at /home/user/public/test.txt while on the server.

On the windows client I can see the file. I can change the file. I can close the file, reopen it and it see that it did indeed write. But when I go to the server and try to open the file, there is nothing inside.

Similarly I have transferred 300gb of photos to Z:/public/DCIM/ that I cannot see while physically on the Ubuntu server.

When I use df -H my 2TB drive only shows 8GB used instead of 308GB.

I’m not sure if this is a filesystem thing, a permission thing, or what. The shared drive is ext4.

Comment: Does this : https://askubuntu.com/a/1412091/653727 answer the question?

Comment: I will add that https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server recommends using /srv/samba not ~/Public